# ionic / cordova install error win10

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

i have installed nodejs 8 but getting these errors. really stucked
plz answer first

```
C:\Users\Muna\Ionic>npm install -g cordova
```

> npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: validate-npm-package license@3.0.1 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\validate-npm-package-license):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\validate-npm-package-license-daa56318\LICENSE'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: cordova-js@4.2.1 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-js):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\cordova-js-4a835737\test\test.urlutil.js'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: express@4.15.3 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\express):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\express-2ec03f1c\History.md'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: plist@2.0.1 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\simple-plist\node_modules\plist):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\plist-7947d2c9\dist\plist-parse.js'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: plist@2.0.1 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\plist):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\plist-dcf4d866\dist\plist.js'
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: shelljs@0.7.8 (node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-fetch\node_modules\shelljs):
>
> npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, utime 'C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\shelljs-0c2f6ee0\CHANGELOG.md'
>
> npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
>
> npm ERR! sha1-wDv04BywhtW15azorQr+eInWOMM= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-wDv04BywhtW15azorQr+eInWOMM= but got sha1-19b+iGSs/lBl8/MlbaD2iJRtf/g=. (2239 bytes)
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Muna\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-06-19T03_20_22_610Z-debug.log

Comment: Please remove angularjs tag as it is not related to your question.

Comment: Looks like a bad download. Clear your npm_modues and try agan. The directories to clear are mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error while installing another app,
Two possible solutions I found after spending 5 hours. First one worked for me.

1. `npm install npm@4.6 -g`
2. `npm cache clean --force` or `npm cache verify`

Hope it helps!